# Deleting the LinkedList content (destructor)

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a quick question on how my destructor going to invoke in the code below. I have the `~LinkedList()` destructor calling custom `clear()` function to free dynamic memory.

So, if I want to delete the `LinkedList ll_one`, how should I do that (in source.cpp below)? Something like the output below:

> Outputting Linked List one...
>
> Linked List one { 19, 18, 17, 16, 15 }
>
> Destructor called
>
> Outputting Linked List one...
>
> Linked List one {  }

---

```
//Node.h
#ifndef NODE
#define NODE
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;

    Node(int i) : value(i), next(nullptr) {}
    Node() : value(0), next(nullptr) {}
};
#endif /*NODE*/
```

---

```
//LinkedList.h
#ifndef LINKEDLIST
#define LINKEDLIST
#include <ostream>
#include "Node.h"

class LinkedList {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    std::string name;

    void recursePrint(Node*, std::ostream&) const;

public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(std::string);
    // destrcutor declaration
    ~LinkedList();
    void setName(std::string);
    std::string getName() const;
     
    void insertFront(int);
    void insertBack(int);
    void clear();
    void print() const;
    void print(std::ostream&) const;
    void printReverse() const;
    void printReverse(std::ostream&) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedList&);

};
#endif /*LINKEDLIST*/
```

---

```
//LinkedList.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
LinkedList::LinkedList(string name) : 
    head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), name(name) {}

// Define destructor
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    cout << "caling destructor" << endl;
    clear();
}

void LinkedList::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

string LinkedList::getName() const{
    return name;
}

void LinkedList::insertFront(int value) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(value);
    newNode->next = head; // attach to list
    head = newNode;
    if (tail == nullptr) { // empty list
        tail = newNode; // only node is both head and tail
    }
}

void LinkedList::insertBack(int value) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(value);
    if (tail != nullptr)
        tail->next = newNode; // attach to list
    tail = newNode;
    if (head == nullptr) { // empty list
        head = newNode; // only node is both head and tail
    }
}

// Define
void LinkedList::clear() {
    Node* temp;
    while (head != NULL) {
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
    head = tail = NULL;


}

void LinkedList::print() const {
    print(cout);
}

void LinkedList::print(ostream& os) const {
    os << this;
}

void LinkedList::printReverse() const {
    printReverse(cout);
}

void LinkedList::printReverse(ostream& os) const {
    os << this->name << ": ";
    Node* current = this->head;
    if (current == nullptr) {
        os << "<Empty List>";
    }
    else
        recursePrint(current, os);
    os << endl;
}

void LinkedList::recursePrint(Node* node, ostream& os) const {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        recursePrint(node->next, os);
        os << node->value << " ";
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const LinkedList& ll) {
    os << ll.getName() << " {";
    Node* current = ll.head;
    if (current == nullptr) {
        os << " <Empty List>";
    }
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current != ll.head)
            cout << ",";
        cout << " " << current->value;
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << " }";
    return os;
}
```

---

```
//Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    LinkedList ll_one("Linked List one");
    int num = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 15; i < 20; ++i) {
        ll_one.insertFront(i);
    }
    cout << "Outputting Linked List one..." << endl;
    cout << ll_one << endl;
     
    // How to delete the ll_one?
    cout << "Outputting Linked List one..." << endl;
    cout << ll_one << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Destructor will also be called at the very last `}` (end of the scope)

Comment: In your given code, `ll_one` will have its destructor called automatically. As long as your destructor does the right thing, you're done. No need to explicitly delete things. That is the purpose of destructors.

Comment: @GManNickG While this is 100% correct, I think that OP understands that and wants to know how to release memory of the linked list prior to end of the scope.

Comment: Unrelated, you can avoid the `if (head == nullptr)` clause in your `insertBack` by hanging the `head` assignment as an `else` to the `if (tail != nullptr)` condition.

Comment: ll_one.clear() calls the custom function. But I'm just wondering is there a way to see when the destructor is invoked before the end of the scope? May be deleting the head of the list? I'm preparing a tutorial for a lab work, so this helps students to see the functionality of the destructor. Something like the output posted above (just updated)

Answer (score 0):

ll_one is created on the stack. When that object leaves the scope of main it will automatically be popped off, and its destructor will be called. You should only have to manually call delete if you allocate it on the heap.

Here is an example of it being allocated on the heap.

```
LinkedList* ll_one = new LinkedList();
delete ll_one;
```

If you want to empty the list, or free up any space it is using before its deleted then you call clear.

Heap

```
LinkedList* ll_one = new LinkedList();
ll_one->clear();
delete ll_one;
```

Stack

```
LinkedList ll_one;
ll_one.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm wondering, if it is in the scope of main, is there a way to display the cout from the destructor before it goes out of scope? I'm trying to see whether I can do this without making changes to the current structure.